# uwsgi attach-daemon before python process starts

Tags: python, process, uwsgi

I have a separate process that I want to run alongside the python process I have managed by uWSGI. I wanted to use the `attach-daemon` option to start this process, but it seems that bash command specified in `attach-daemon` does not get called until *after* the python process' app gets started up. However, I need the process to be running *before* the python process starts up in order for everything to run correctly. Is there any way to specify which order things get started in? It's not even necessary to me that I use `attach-daemon`, if there's a simpler way to initialize a set of managed processes in a defined order.

Answer (score 2):

Use --lazy-apps, in this way the app will be loaded by each worker after the master has been fully spawned (and its external daemons started)